# How to check if one of several fields is in the set?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am generating the SQL queries from the C++ code. (sqllite3)

I need to write efficiently the following request.

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE T.field1 IN (V1, V2, V3, ...) or T.field2 IN (V1, V2, V3, ...);
```

How to optimize it: avoid pasting two times (V1, V2, V3, ...), or take sets intersection of (T.field1, T.field2) and (V1, V2, V3, ...), or create statement local variable (V1, V2, V3, ...), or whatever?

The SQL statement is created as a string and then passed to the SQL-parse engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `CTE` with the values and use it like this:

```
WITH cte(x) AS (VALUES (V1), (V2), (V3), ....)
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE T.field1 IN (SELECT * FROM cte) 
   OR T.field2 IN (SELECT * FROM cte);
```

Comment: Hm...
Is it better than the original statement?

Comment: If you have a really long list of values I guess it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could flip the conditions:

```
where v1 in (t.field1, t.field2) or
      v2 in (t.field1, t.field2) or
      . . .
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but it doesn't make any sense. The amount of fields is often smaller than the number of elements in the set, so the query will be much longer than it should be.

Comment: @HlibPylypets . . . This answers your question, because each value only needs to be inserted once into the query.  From a performance perspective, I would expect all the queries to have similar performance -- requiring a full-table scan.